# Slug Data from Api call not displaying in window with reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm pretty sure I did everything right in this code below but I have no idea why the data in the clientside won't display. When I try to console the result in the UseEffect hook but and I get all data but using them in the html just doesn't work.

What worries me more is that this code worked fine for a short time before it totally stopped displaying these details in the html

```
import React, {
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useReducer,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL, getError } from '../utils';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import moment from 'moment';
import MessageBox from './MessageBox';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import LoadingBox from './LoadingBox';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, blog: action.payload, loading: false };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function BlogpostScreen() {
  let reviewsRef = useRef();

  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

  const params = useParams();
  const { slug } = params;

  const [{ loading, error, blog }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      blog: {},
      loading: true,
      error: '',
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/blogs/slug/${slug}`);
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err.message) });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [slug]);

  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;

  return (
    <div className="position-relative mb-3">
      <img
        className="img-fluid w-100"
        src={blog.image}
        alt={blog.name}
        style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
      />
      <div className="bg-white border border-top-0 p-4">
        <div className="mb-3">
          <Link
            className="badge badge-primary text-uppercase font-weight-semi-bold p-2 mr-2"
            to={{
              pathname: '/search',
              search: `category=${blog.category}`,
            }}
          >
            {blog.category}
          </Link>
          <a className="text-body" href="/">
            {moment(blog.createdAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}
          </a>
        </div>
        <h1 className="mb-3 text-secondary text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
          {blog.name}
        </h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blog.post }}></div>
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between bg-white border border-top-0 p-4">
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
          <img
            className="rounded-circle mr-2"
            src="img/user.jpg"
            width="25"
            height="25"
            alt=""
          />
          <span>KimmoTech</span>
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
          <span className="ml-3">
            <i className="far fa-eye mr-2"></i>
            {blog.views}
          </span>
          <span className="ml-3">
            <i className="far fa-comment mr-2"></i>
            {blog.numReviews}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the backend, I had this:

```
blogRouter.get('/slug/:slug', async (req, res) => {
  const blog = await Blog.findOneAndUpdate(
    { slug: req.params.slug },
    { $inc: { views: 1 } },
    { new: true }
  );
  if (blog) {
    res.send({blog});
  } else {
    res.status(404).sendStatus({ message: 'Blogpost Not Found' });
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @RubenSmn no, there are no errors in the console and I receive a 200 statusCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue was because I was sending an object like this `res.send({blog});` to the frontend. So I changed

this:

```
blogRouter.get('/slug/:slug', async (req, res) => {
  const blog = await Blog.findOneAndUpdate(
    { slug: req.params.slug },
    { $inc: { views: 1 } },
    { new: true }
  );
  if (blog) {
    res.send({blog});
  } else {
    res.status(404).sendStatus({ message: 'Blogpost Not Found' });
  }
});
```

to this:

```
blogRouter.get('/slug/:slug', async (req, res) => {
  const blog = await Blog.findOneAndUpdate(
    { slug: req.params.slug },
    { $inc: { views: 1 } },
    { new: true }
  );
  if (blog) {
    res.send(blog);
  } else {
    res.status(404).sendStatus({ message: 'Blogpost Not Found' });
  }
});
```